# Correct Event to check user authentication in BaseController class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm in the process of converting a web application of mine to an MVC application. I think it will benefit from it but I'm a newb and a half at MVC. I want all of my controllers to inherent from a base controller and the first thing I want to do is redirect the User to the Login view if they are not authenticated. The method already written basically looks for a Cookie and if it doesn't find it does a Response.Redirect() to the login screen. I want to move this method to the BaseController but I'm not positive what's the best way to go about it. So in essence what BaseController Event should I invoke to check for authentication before loading the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC way to handle this is to decorate controller actions with the [AuthorizationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx).

> When you mark an action method with AuthorizeAttribute, access to that action method is restricted to users who are both authenticated and authorized. If you mark a controller with the attribute, all action methods in the controller are restricted.
>
> The Authorize attribute lets you indicate that authorization is restricted to predefined roles or to individual users. This gives you a high degree of control over who is authorized to view any page on the site.
>
> If an unauthorized user tries to access a method that is marked with the Authorize attribute, the MVC framework returns a 401 HTTP status code. If the site is configured to use ASP.NET forms authentication, the 401 status code causes the browser to redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: +1 this is awesome So can you give me a short walkthrough on how to do this with a BaseController so that is does this to all controllers? The example on the link provided was for each individual class.

Comment: A custom base controller was recommended to handle authorization for MVC 1 and MVC 2, but not anymore.  See http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/04/18/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous.aspx